# Add a filter to a mediawiki table

Tags: datatables, mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I have a large table in a mediawiki that I want to be able to filter. I've just installed Semantic Mediawiki thinking that the [Datatables format](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Datatables_format) (based on the datatables jQuery library) in the Semantic Results Format might help me do this, but it seems it's only available if a table is being generated dynamically as part of a parser query (eg, data from elsewhere in the wiki).

Is this accurate or does it contain a way to format an existing table, in a similar way to the built in `|class="wikitable sortable"` can do? I can't find any documentation to suggest this is possible.